# Nlog dependency injection issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nlog

In a console app (.NET6) I prepare the ConfigurationBuilder and the ServiceCollection

```
var log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true)
 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
.AddSystemsManager(path: $"/xxx/")
.Build();

    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    serviceCollection
    .AddTransient<IParentPublisher, ParentPublisher>()
    .AddDbContext<LPContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["connectionstring-ec2"]),
        ServiceLifetime.Transient
     )
    .AddScoped<IConfiguration>(_ => configuration)
    .AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        // configure Logging with NLog
        loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
        loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(configuration);
    });


var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

log.Info("Starting...");

var parentPublisher = serviceProvider.GetService<IParentPublisher>();
parentPublisher.DoSomething();
```

But when I try to log to console with `log.Info("Starting...");` nothing appears on the console.

Also, in the `ParentPublisher` service I inject `ILogger<ParentPublisher> logger`, and all logs (including Microsoft debug logs) are shown, even if I specify to log only `Error` level.
What am I doing wrong? Dependency injection seems to loose Nlog configuration, and main seems to ignore configuration.

Here's appsettings.json section regarding Nlog:

```
"NLog": {
"rules": {
  "Microsoft": {
    "logger": "Microsoft.*",
    "minLevel": "Error",
    "final": true
  },
  "999": {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Trace",
    "writeTo": "console"
  }
},
"targets": {
  "console": {
    "type": "Console",
    "layout": "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
  }
}
```

}

And here's appsettings.Development.json

```
"NLog": {
"rules": {
  "Microsoft": {
    "logger": "Microsoft.*",
    "minLevel": "Error",
    "final": true
  },
  "999": {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Trace",
    "writeTo": "console"
  }
},
"targets": {
  "console": {
    "type": "Console",
    "layout": "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
  }
}
```

}

UPDATE:

main is ok now, logs are handled correctly.
`ParentPublisher` service which injects `ILogger<ParentPublisher> logger` derives from a base class:

```
public ParentPublisher(LPContext context, 
        IAmazonSimpleNotificationService snsClient, 
        IConfiguration configuration,
        ILogger<ParentPublisher> logger
        ) : base(context, configuration)
```

Should I pass logger to the base class? Because actually I realize that all EFCore logs are emitted by the base class operations, even though Appsettings.json are filtering them.

UPDATE 2:
using NLog fluent API everything works fine, so the problem is not related to dependency injection, I guess it's related to Appsettings.json file

```
var log= LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(builder =>
{
    // turn off microsoft logging, unless errors
    builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Error);

    var consoleTarget = builder.ForTarget("console").WriteTo(new ConsoleTarget()).WithAsync();
    var awsTarget = builder.ForTarget("aws").WriteTo(new AWSTarget()
    {
        LogGroup = "/dotnet/MessageQueueProcessor/nlog"

    }).WithAsync();
    builder.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteTo(consoleTarget);
    builder.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteTo(awsTarget);
}).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Here is a simple example of console-application with dependency-injection: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/tree/master/examples/NetCore2/ConsoleExampleJsonConfig (Notice it is a good idea to update to NLog.Extension.Logging v5 for better out-of-the-box experience)

Comment: Good idea to add `"throwConfigExceptions": true` to discover issues with invalid logging-configuration in [appsetting.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Comment: The service parentPublisher in the example code injects Ilogger.
parentPublisher  derives from a base class which uses DbContext to perform some basic actions. This base class emits lot of debug and warnings related to EFCore, ignoring NLog config from Appsettings.json